# XSL - how to find and get the first previous text to the current node

Tags: xslt

Using XSL, I am trying to get the first previous text {Male/Female} to the current node {field}.  The number of elements between {Field} and the previous text element will vary.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<tablecell>
    <par def="2">Male/Female</par>
</tablecell>
<tablecell>
    <par def="3">
         <field usenotesstyle="false" 
                height="0.2500in" 
                width="1in" 
                multiline="true" 
                borderstyle="single" 
                lookupeachchar="false" 
                lookupaddressonrefresh="false"
                type="keyword" 
                kind="editable" 
                name="Sex">
             <keywords helperbutton="false" 
                       columns="1" 
                       ui="listbox">
                 <textlist>
                     <text>Male</text>
                     <text>Female</text>
                 </textlist>
             </keywords>
         </field>
     </par>
 </tablecell>
```

Comment: THANK YOU !!!   The second suggestion worked

Comment: I just noticed that there are some previous text items that I do not want to include.  For example, "<formula>ItemStatus ="Found"</formula>".  If I encounter this first, I want to keep proceeding to the next previous.  Is that possible?  So skip formula and keep looking backward

Comment: Yes, it's possible - but you need to provide us with clear criteria which nodes to exclude (or include).

Comment: thank you.  There will be several.   "formula", "text", etc...  I tried the following - but it seems to be not working:

Comment: <td><xsl:value-of select="substring(preceding::text()[not(normalize-space() = '') and not(contains(name(..), 'formula'))][1],1,12)"/></td>

Comment: Sorry - I does seem to be working now....."and not(contains(name(..), 'formula'))"

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to get the first previous text {Male/Female} to the
>   current node {field}

How about:

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding::text()[1]"/>
```

Comment: One might need to specify `preceding::text()[not(normalize-space() = '')][1]` to avoid matching the whitespace-only text node between the start-tag of `par` and the start-tag of `field`.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen More often than not, I will have `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`at the top of my stylesheet. So while you do have a point, the real point here is to always work with a complete example rather than snippets taken out of context.